# Implement C# interface in an unmanaged cpp dll

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, interface, add-on

I have a C# apllication having add-ons capability. An add-on/plug-in that implements a specific interface can be linked/loaded at runtime to the main C# application.

Now to my question: how can I develop an unmanaged cpp dll that implements the C# interface and be loaded runtime to the C# app?

Thanks,
Cabbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement interface using p/inkove, for example:

```
public interface IDirectory
{
    bool IsDirectoryEmplty(string path);
}

public class Directory : IDirectory
{
    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PathIsDirectoryEmpty")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool IsDirectoryEmplty([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string directory);

    bool IInterface.IsDirectoryEmplty(string path)
    {
        return IsDirectoryEmplty(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any conception about the performance compared to just calling a C# method? Is there much overhead?

Comment: i think, such implementation (exteranal c/c++) can be used only for large computing

Answer (score 0):

With `common language support` on, you can write managed dll with full native c++ capability mixed in.

And you can load unmanaged dll via PInvoke in .Net, but I'd rather not recommend that way.

Comment: why you do not recommend 'PInvoke'?

Comment: @Cabbi C++/CLI is way easier to write than PInvoke. And even for the most of time just a little, C++/CLI is faster than PInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you cannot have an *unmanaged* DLL that implements a C# (managed) interface.

However, you can create a [mixed mode assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx), that might be what you want. This is a very common way to provide a native C++ (unmanaged) implementation with a .NET wrapper making it an assembly that looks managed to a C# (or other .NET language) consumer.

In addition, you can use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx) to consume a pure native DLL from a NET assembly.

Comment: ...I didn't know about mixed mode, nice!

Comment: I'll investigate on the 'PInvoke' overhead.